# Load substitute static content when remote server doesn't respond

Tags: drupal, simplexml, feed

OK not sure how to even ask this question, but I have to pull these feeds through a remote server using simplexml but I notice that when the server is down, it kind of crashes my entire site (built with Drupal) so I'm wondering if there is a way to tell my site not to load the remote server's feeds if there is a problem and to load static substitute content instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use some error handler to show your static content when you get errors.
Have a look at this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php